# limits as x goes to negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals, fractions, infinity

What is the limit of this:

$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (4x^2 + 3x)^\frac 12 + 2x$

I tried to use conjugates and then divide by the highest degree of $x$ but I got $\frac 30$ which is not the right answer of $-\frac 34$. Is the process that I took correct, can I use algebra or do you have to think logically?

Comment: Please check the edited question and see if there are any mistakes.

Comment: астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг the limit is to negative infinity, thank you for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2+3x}+2x\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{4x^2+3x-4x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+3x}-2x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{3}{-\sqrt{4+\frac{3}{x}}-2}=-\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: where did that negative come from in the third limit?

Comment: @Bushra: Note that $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: so when x→−∞ you automatically put a negative in front?

Comment: @Bushra For $x<0$ we have $\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+3x}}{x}=-\sqrt{4+\frac{3}{x}}.$

Answer (score 1):

You have  $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (4x^2 + 3x)^\frac 12 + 2x
=\lim_{x \to \infty} (4x^2 - 3x)^\frac 12 - 2x.
$$ Now
\begin{align}
 (4x^2 - 3x)^\frac 12 - 2x&=\frac{4x^2-3x-4x^2}{(4x^2-3x)^{1/2}+2x}
=\frac{-3x}{(4x^2-3x)^{1/2}+2x}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{-3}{(4-3/x)^{1/2}+2}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}-\frac34.
\end{align}

Comment: What does it mean to change the limit? How can you do that? What is that concept?

Comment: Change $x$ to $-x$.